# Can we see the status of a question when reviewing edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, edits

A few moments ago, I accepted a suggested edit to a pretty poor [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467126/java-class-expected-error).

Looking at it, I felt that while the question still wasn't perfect, the edit was an improvement and perhaps could aid to drawing an appropriate answer. After clicking accept, I went back to the question to leave a comment to the OP of the post as well.

That's when I realized the question had already been closed, and suddenly I regret my decision because I started to realize that while the edit was an improvement, it didn't *really* make the question any better for SO. I made a mistake, and it wasn't until I saw other users close the question as off topic that it hit me.

I believe it would be helpful if reviewers could see the status of a question if it has been put on hold, as well as the reason why. As a reviewer, it's not always black and white to me whether or not to approve edits on certain questions that were originally poor; A good question asked in a poor manor can easily go unnoticed on the forum, so any edit to improve that question could be helpful.

In this particular case, while the edit improved the question, I don't think it made it any more worthy of being reopened. This is something I overlooked, and I know I am not the first or last person to do so. However, had I seen some sort of signal that the question had already been closed, I likely would have asked myself if the edit was beneficial enough to change that.

Does anyone else think that the status of a question should be included in the edit review queue (if necessary)? Are there other benefits, and is there a consequence to having that extra information?

---

*I am open to the discussion of whether or not I should/shouldn't have approved that edit, or if I am approaching it the wrong way, but I hope that the feature request can be independent of this example.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status of the question **shouldn't** affect your decision to edit it.  If the edit is substantial and good enough, the question stands a chance of being *re*opened, which is a good thing.

So let it be said that I don't think that such a feature would be a good idea.  It'd harm more than help, as there are questions which are good that could use a bit of polish out there.

That said, this is one of those cases in which an editor must be a bit more vigilant.  Edit those questions which actually stand a chance of helping others out and have some lasting value for the site.  If we pare down the contents of this question, here's what we get:

> I have the following code: (*syntatically incorrect code here*)
>
> I get the following errors:  (*compiler informing user of syntatically incorrect code here*)
>
> Please help!

There's nothing here that I see helping anyone more than a guide on Java syntax, which could be found anywhere else on the 'Net.  It's not a question I'd have deemed worth editing, and any edits on it I'd have probably said in a custom response something to that effect.